# Does multiprocessing.pool.map erase map object?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

When I apply `multiprocessing.pool.map` to `list` object, the `list` object would not be affected:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def identity(x):
    return x

num_list = list(range(0, 10))

print("before multiprocessing:")
with Pool(10) as p:
    print(p.map(identity, num_list))

print("after multiprocessing:")
print(list(num_list))
```

prints

```
before multiprocessing:
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
after multiprocessing:
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

But when I apply `multiprocessing.pool.map` upon `map` object, it seems to got erased:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def identity(x):
    return x

num_list = list(range(0, 10))
num_list = map(identity, num_list)

print("before multiprocessing:")
with Pool(10) as p:
    print(p.map(identity, num_list))

print("after multiprocessing:")
print(list(num_list))
```

prints

```
before multiprocessing:
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
after multiprocessing:
[]
```

The only difference is `num_list = map(identity, num_list)`.

Does `num_list`(map object) got erased by  `multiprocessing.pool.map`?

I'm not sure about this but I couldn't find another explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`map` function return an `iterator`， After `p.map()` traversing the last element of the `map` obj, it will return nothing when accessing the `map` obj again. This is the feature of the iterator